# Can the following be solved algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got this problem from a book that is about 20 years old. It's a simple enough inequality and I can solve it with a basic graphing calculator easily. However, I was wondering if I could solve it algebraically. Don't see how yet, and I am trying from all angles. Here it is,
$x^3-3x+1\leq 0$.

Comment: Entirely possible to solve equality; this is what is known as a "depressed cubic" and it can be handled via Cardano's method. More on Brilliant [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cardano-method/). Handling inequality should be trivial with that.

Comment: Thank you. I checked out the Brilliant link, got the idea clear in my head. However, I have a nagging feeling that I am missing something obvious. Because, the Cardano's method was not mentioned in this chapter anywhere, and the question asks for both graphic and algebraic solution. However I found Cardano's method discussed as an Impractial way of solving equations at a later section of the same text book. I am still trying to see a more straight forward method. Will come back here again.

Comment: Equations of degree 3 have algebraic solutions using the Cardano method and yes, the method is not extremely practical, but it is the only one. It is a degree-3 analogue of the known formula for the roots of a polynomial of degree 2.

Comment: Thanks to all. I guess I have to learn to live with Cardano then.

Comment: Or with Lagrange: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Lagrange's_method

Comment: There is also a geometric method , avoiding to be forced to use ugly complex roots if all roots are real. But both methods are so complicated that they are usually not used and the roots are determined numerically. For degree $4$ , there is still a method to exactly solve it , but it is already extremely complicated. For degree $5$ and higher , there is no universal formula.